# Cannot infer type arguments for Class<>

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with my sorting-test app, where I use a comparator.
I got a message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Cannot infer type arguments for Sorter<>

For that code:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

            Sorter<Person> idSorter = new Sorter<>(new idComparator());
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

Sorter class:

```
public class Sorter<T extends Comparable> {

    Comparator<T> comparator;
    int switches = 0,
        compares = 0;

    public Sorter(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public Sorter() {
        this.comparator = null;
    }

    protected int compare(T first, T second) {
        if (this.comparator == null) {
            int cmp = first.compareTo(second);
            this.compares++;
            return cmp;
        }
```

Comparable interface:

```
public interface Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Comparable other);
}
```

idComparator class:

```
public class idComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    public int compare(Integer first, Integer second) {
        return first > second? 1: first == second? 0: 1;
    }
}
```

Comparator interface:

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
    int compare(T first, T second);
}
```

What is wrong with such a use? How can I do it better?

Comment: How can a `Comparator<Integer>` be used to sort `Person` ? You need to map from Person to personId first.

Comment: `idComparator` should probably be a `Comparator<Person>` and compare `first.getId()` with `second.getId()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it, but `T extends Comparable>` uses a raw type (`Comparable`). Raw types often have weird rules. Try turning that into `T extends  Cinch Comparable<T>>` instead. (You can read that as, "some type T that can be compared against itself")

Comment: If you're getting that error, that means you're trying to run the code even though the compilation failed. Why are you dong that? Fix compilation errors and recompile *before* running the code.

Comment: Why are you declaring a `Comparator` interface when it [already exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in the Java Runtime Library?

Comment: @Andreas oops. Ignore that word. Typing on a phone :)

Comment: @Thilo - thank you, your solution helps me a lot! :)

Comment: Just a passing comment...  class names starting with lowercase letters are... unsavory.  Naming conventions help people to know when you are referring to a type versus a field or method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this line:

```
Sorter<Person> idSorter = new Sorter<>(new idComparator());
```

`idComparator` implements `Comparator<Integer>` so the `T` for `Sorter` is `Integer`, but your declaration *indicates* to the compiler that `T` is `Person`, so the compiler is confused and emits a message.

[Probable fix](https://ideone.com/fdErpt):

```
Sorter<Integer> idSorter = new Sorter<>(new idComparator());
```

but as some said in comments, it's *odd* to sort persons based on some integer.

---

Also note:

- a `return` statement is (possibly) missing in `Sorter#compare`
- `idComparator` name should start with an uppercase letter: `IdComparator`
- if you really want to use your own `Comparable` / `Comparator` you should name them with some other name (`MyComparable`?) `as is`, there is a confusion with java ones.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Java 8 to sort and compare?  For clarification, Lists.newArrayList is a Google Guava collection.

```
public void sortingEntitiesById() {
    List<Person> persons = Lists.newArrayList(new Person("Sarah", 10), new Person("Jack", 12));

    persons.sort((h1, h2) -> h1.getId().compareTo(h2.getId()));
    Assert.assertThat(persons.get(0), equalTo(new Person("Sarah", 10)));
}
```

Reverse Sort

```
public void sortingEntitiesByIdReversed() {
    List<Person> persons = Lists.newArrayList(new Person("Sarah", 10), new Person("Jack", 12));
    Comparator<Person> comparator = (h1, h2) -> h1.getId().compareTo(h2.getId());

    persons.sort(comparator.reversed());
    Assert.assertThat(persons.get(0), equalTo(new Person("Jack", 12)));
}
```

Sort with multiple conditions

```
public void sortEntitiesWithMultipleConditions() {
    List<Person> persons = Lists.newArrayList(
            new Person("Sarah", 12), new Person("Sarah", 10), new Person("Zack", 12));

    persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).thenComparing(Person::getId));
    Assert.assertThat(persons.get(0), equalTo(new Person("Sarah", 10)));
}
```

Comment: Question is not about unit tests, so that will likely confuse OP. --- Question is about sorting by ID, not by Name. --- Question is implementing a custom `Sorter` class, so this is an *exercise/assignment*. --- What is `Lists.newArrayList`? Not standard Java, for sure.

Comment: The Java 8 way would be `persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName))`.

Comment: Lists.newArrayList is one of the builders from Google Guava collection which is highly used.

Comment: This is just a simple Unit test that shows the implementation example that could be copied and executed without any issues.

Comment: If OP is not already using Guava, adding it is way overkill just for getting `Lists.newArrayList`, and "highly used" is a relative concept. Since question wasn't tagged `android`, how "highly used" do you think Guava is among non-android Java developers? A simple change to `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` makes the answer relevant to all Java developers, not just Guava users. And since question wasn't tagged `junit` or showed any unit test code, removing `@Test` and `Assert.assertThat(...)` will not take away any relevance to your answer, but will stop mingling in irrelevant stuff.

Comment: These examples demonstrate using Lambda Expressions which are part of Java 8.